# The naughty friend and the mysterious note

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

A total of 10 friends came to my house for a party.

Halfway through the party, while we were having dinner, I noticed only 9 friends present in the dining room.  A few minutes later, the missing friend came out from my study and joined our dinner.

After the party ended, I entered my study and saw a note:

> Nice. Gotta crack that secret now

Unsure of its meaning, I put it away.  As a music fan, I started my computer and typed "Never Gonna Give You Up" into the YouTube search bar, only to find a bunch of digits on the screen:

> 20247

I began to suspect that the naughty friend had sabotaged my computer.  Curious, I proceeded to type the lyrics to Never Gonna Give You Up by Rick Astley, and here was the result:

> 36557
> 47571238
> 1285674
> 45436400
>
> 83784862
> 7144
>
> 20247
> 20842
> 2083124
> 20144
> 2004
> 20812144
>
> 3440822
> 83828255504
> 35777866
> 575713074
>
> 13421862
> 58125458
>
> 20247
> 20842
> 2083124
> 20144
> 2004
> 20812144

Increasingly confused, I started to wonder:
what could possibly be the meaning of that note?

---

The lyrics for reference:

> We’re no strangers to love
> You know the rules and so do I
> A full commitment’s what I’m thinking of
> You wouldn’t get this from any other guy
>
> I just wanna tell you how I’m feeling
> Gotta make you understand
>
> Never gonna give you up
> Never gonna let you down
> Never gonna run around and desert you
> Never gonna make you cry
> Never gonna say goodbye
> Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you
>
> We’ve known each other for so long
> Your heart’s been aching but you’re too shy to say it
> Inside we both know what’s been going on
> We know the game and we’re gonna play it
>
> And if you ask me how I’m feeling
> Don’t tell me you’re too blind to see
>
> Never gonna give you up
> Never gonna let you down
> Never gonna run around and desert you
> Never gonna make you cry
> Never gonna say goodbye
> Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you

Comment: I feel Rick Rolled... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first and most obvious thing to notice is that

> we appear to have one digit for each word in the lyrics, and when the same word recurs so does the same digit. So there is apparently a mapping from words to digits, which we need to find.

The next is that

> the digits that appear are precisely 0..8; there are no 9s. This suggests that maybe we are reducing something modulo 9. For some reason, there are fewer of {0,1,6} than of {2,3,4,5,7,8}, but this is probably just coincidence.

It looks as if

> case is not significant, because "a" and "A" both map to 1, and "You" and "you" to 4. Also, "no" and "on" both map to 6, suggesting that maybe we're just adding up per-letter values (or multiplying them or something, but adding seems simplest and most likely). The fact that a->1 seems promising, too. I guess that we will ignore the apostrophes.

Let's run with this idea and see whether it works.

> We have you=4, your=8, youre=2 so if we're just adding things per letter then r=4, e=3. That makes the earlier observation that a=1 look less hopeful. We have we=5 and were=3, which is at least consistent with this. Let's keep trying to build up a mapping from letters to values and see what it looks like. If we=5 and e=3 then w=2... oh, that's suggestive. QWERTY keyboard column numbers? Yup, that seems to work.

So what's happening is that

> each letter key is being translated into its position in its keyboard row (apparently apostrophes and spaces do nothing) and then each word is replaced by the sum of its letters' values, modulo 9.

Comment: Well done!  Now you can go a step further and figure out what the content of the note means :)

Comment: rot13(Ol gur jnl, gur gra sevraqf ner fhccbfrq gb fvtavsl gur gra qvtvgf, jvgu gur zvffvat anhtugl sevraq orvat avar, juvpu vf abg bayl zvffvat va gur bhgchg ohg nyfb na rffragvny cneg bs gur genafyngvat nytbevguz)

Comment: It seems to me that rot13(gurer'f n zber boivbhf qvtvg sbe n sevraq fcrpvsvpnyyl qrfpevorq nf "anhtugl" gb ercerfrag)... As for the note, it seems to say rot13(r) but it's not obvious to me what actual significance that has.

Comment: rot13(Gur "boivbhf" rkcynangvba bs "anhtugl" vf boivbhf abj gung lbh zragvba vg!  Fbzrubj vg rfpncrq zl zvaq juvyr V jnf pensgvat gur chmmyr.)  Indeed - the note refers to the number, which is simply an Easter egg for the puzzle with no real significance.  By the way, I am really impressed by the way you looked for clues and put them together to solve the algorithm.